# How to stop RXJS chain when a condition is not respected?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my project I have a Reactive form with a validate button and I want to prevent multiclick, and multi calling of backend.

So I made this in `component.html`:

```html
<button #boutonValider></button>
```

In `component.ts`:

```js
@ViewChild('boutonValider', { static: true }) boutonValider: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.validationCreationDecision();
}

validationCreationDecision() {
    fromEvent(this.boutonValider.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
    map( () => if(this.isValidForm()){   //condition for http call, I would like to stop the chain if the condition is not respected
    this.initializeInputHttp();    
       }),
    exhaustMap(inputHttp =>
         this.decisionExonerationService.creerDecisionExoneration(inputHttp) //Http call, don't want to call if form is not valid
         )  
    ).subscribe(resp => console.log(resp))
}
```

Is there any solutions to stop RxJs chain when a condition is not respected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think debounceTime and filter can manage your scenario.

```
validationCreationDecision() {
    fromEvent(this.boutonValider.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(

// time in ms to manage between each event (click) before emit 
// define value you want in your scenario
// https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime

    debounceTime(600), 

// apply filter to chain
// https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter

    filter(() => this.isValidForm()),

    map( () => this.initializeInputHttp()),
    exhaustMap(inputHttp =>
          this.decisionExonerationService.creerDecisionExoneration(inputHttp) //Http call, don't want to call if form is not valid
        )  
          ).subscribe(resp => console.log(resp))
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`map()` emits the value returned by the project function, so you can return an appropriate value based on the condition and then check that value in the next chain stage:

```
    validationCreationDecision() {
    fromEvent(this.boutonValider.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
        map(() => {
            if (this.isValidForm()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }),
        exhaustMap(check => {
            if (check) {
                doSth();
            } 
        })
    ).subscribe(resp => console.log(resp))
  }
```